# CodePipeline - CodeBuildStage with overridden artifact upload location

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

I have an existing CodePipeline which listens to changes to a CodeCommit repository and triggers a CodeBuild of a build project with specific environment variables and a specific artifact upload location. Is there a way to create another CodeBuild step where the same build project is run but with overridden environment variables and another artifact upload location, or will I have to create another build project with these settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up the CodeBuild project to allow the build to override artifact names when using S3 as the artifact location. Each artifact has a `OverrideArtifactName` (in the console it is a checkbox called 'Enable semantic versioning') property that is a boolean. If you set this to `true` the `buildspec` will need to specify the name of the file in the `artifacts` section. While this field is called `name`, it can include the path as well. That means that you can calculate the name (including the path) based on values inside the build spec (including using environment variables).